# Encapsulamento Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber se eu posso encapsular uma função que não esta em uma classe, tipo, só uma função no código mesmo, para que ela só seja acessada dentro do arquivo, e quando eu importar esse arquivo eu não consiga acessar essa função diretamente.

Comment: Se você prefixar o nome da função com um `_`, tipo `def _funcao`, ao fazer `from modulo import *` ele não será importado, mas `import _funcao` continua funcionando. Isso serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não temos um encapsulamento semelhante a de outras linguagens. Existe sim uma maneira de se mostrar que algo é encapsulado, porém, segundo a filosofia "Pythônica" todos nós somos adultos (diferente do que meu professor de java acha, falando que todos os usuários são antas e devem ser protegidas). Em python, a maneira de mostrar que certo método ou atributo é privado, e não deve ser usado é colocar `_` na frente dos respectivos nomes.